# Can Python read line from file with \n and print it in 2 lines?

Tags: python, file, escaping

[image]
I made text file in which I wrote:

> My name\n is

in code:

```
with open(file.txt) as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

**output:**

> My name\n is

**I expected:**

> My name
> is

Is there a way to make text file with \n and in program to use string separated in few rows?

Comment: Please add your code directly here, not as a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string variables in python need a way to know where a "new line" should be.

`\n` is a new line signal (make it when press enter)

`\\n` is raw text, usefull when you want to write \n and no excecute a break line. (make it writing '\n')

So, you will need to replace or map '\\n' to '\n'.

The solution:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    Temp=f.read().replace('\\n','\n') # Declare Temp variable is not necesary
    print(Temp)

# Without Temp
with open('file.txt') as f:
    print(f.read().replace('\\n','\n'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    data = f.read().split('\\n')
    for d in data:
        print(d)
```

Here, I simply read the whole file and then splits that into a list by '\n'.